# Remove elements from array of objects MongoDB

Tags: javascript, macos, bash, mongodb

please take a look at my MongoDB 2.4 database: 
trip table:

```
{_id: 1,
"actions": [{ "type": "Flight" }, { "type": "Go" }, { "type": "Train" }, {    "type": "Sleep" }]
},
{_id: 2,
"actions": [{ "type": "Go" }, { "type": "Sleep" }, { "type": "Taxi" }]
},
{_id: 3,
"actions": [{ "type": "Flight" }]
},
{_id: 4
}
```

I want to remove action which type is "Flight", "Taxi", or "Train".
This is my script:

```
db.trip.update({"actions": {$exists: true}}, {$pull: {"actions": {"type": {$in: ["Flight", "Taxi", "Train"]}}}});
```

or:

```
db.trip.update({"actions": {$exists: true}}, {$pull: {"actions": {"type": "Flight"}}});
db.trip.update({"actions": {$exists: true}}, {$pull: {"actions": {"type": "Train"}}});
db.trip.update({"actions": {$exists: true}}, {$pull: {"actions": {"type": "Taxi"}}});
```

No way can solve this requirement. I don't know what is difference of mongoDB on MacOS and centOS. I've test this on 2 OS, test on terminal and MongoHub. Please help me!

The objects after updated will be:

```
{_id: 1,
"actions": [{ "type": "Go" }, {    "type": "Sleep" }]
},
{_id: 2,
"actions": [{ "type": "Go" }, { "type": "Sleep" }]
},
{_id: 3,
"actions": []
},
{_id: 4
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your queries as :

```
db.trip.update({"actions.type": "Flight"}, {$pull: {"actions": {"type": "Flight"}}});
db.trip.update({"actions.type": "Train"}}, {$pull: {"actions": {"type": "Train"}}});
db.trip.update({"actions.type": "Taxi"}}, {$pull: {"actions": {"type": "Taxi"}}});
```

or

```
db.trip.update({"actions" : {$in : [{type : "Flight"}, {type: "Taxi"}, {type : "Train"}]}},{$pull:{"actions" : {$in : [{type : "Flight"}, {type: "Taxi"}, {type : "Train"}]}}},false,true)
```

Comment: Thanks @parvin! The first solution is ok, but when i execute the second - no change happens. And can you explain why my solution is not runnable?